# Geometric interpretation of covariance matrix

Tags: pca, covariance, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

In the following graph, the diagonal elements in the covariance matrix are the same, which I suppose means the spread of data in either direction should be the same, but why the data points are still more elongated in one direction rather than being a circle?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diagonal elements are the variances **in the direction of x, y** whereas the eigenvalues are the magnitude of variances **in the direction of the first and second Principal Components**.